# log4j2 logrotation for elasticsearch doesn't work:q

Tags: elasticsearch, logging, log4j2

I am trying to rotate elasticsearch logs using log4j2 but my configurations do not give me any results and do not delete any logs.

**This configuration does not result in any errors, however I don't see any of my old logs deleted.**

I have added the details as requested by the community members. According to my debug logs elasticsearch starts without error. But doesn't result in any deletion.

My configurations:

```
appender.rolling_old.type = RollingFile
appender.rolling_old.name = rolling_old
appender.rolling_old.fileName = 
   ${sys:es.logs.base_path}${sys:file.separator}${sys:es.logs.cluster_name}.log
appender.rolling_old.policies.time.type = TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling_old.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.rolling_old.layout.pattern = [%d{ISO8601}][%-5p][%-25c{1.}] [%node_name]%marker %m%n
appender.rolling_old.filePattern = 
   ${sys:es.logs.base_path}${sys:file.separator}${sys:es.logs.cluster_name}-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}- 
   %i.log.gz
appender.rolling.policies.time.interval = 1
appender.rolling.policies.time.modulate = true
appender.rolling_old.policies.type = Policies
appender.rolling_old.strategy.type = DefaultRolloverStrategy
appender.rolling_old.strategy.action.type = Delete
appender.rolling_old.strategy.action.basepath = /var/log/elasticsearch
appender.rolling_old.strategy.action.maxDepth = 1
appender.rolling_old.strategy.action.condition.type = IfFileName
appender.rolling_old.strategy.action.condition.glob = elasticsearch-*.log.gz
appender.rolling_old.strategy.action.ifAny.type = IfAny
appender.rolling_old.strategy.action.ifAny.ifLastModified.type = IfLastModified
appender.rolling_old.strategy.action.ifAny.ifLastModified.age = 3D
appender.rolling_old.strategy.action.ifAny.ifAccumulatedFileSize.type = IfAccumulatedFileSize
appender.rolling_old.strategy.action.ifAny.ifAccumulatedFileSize.exceeds = 1MB
```

```
lines 3244-3312/3312 (END)
Feb 11 15:58:58 crait-admin-1 elasticsearch[28653]: 2020-02-11 15:58:58,767 main DEBUG createAgeCondition(age="P3D", ={})
Feb 11 15:58:58 crait-admin-1 elasticsearch[28653]: 2020-02-11 15:58:58,767 main DEBUG org.apache.logging.log4j.core.util.SystemClock supports precise timestamps.
Feb 11 15:58:58 crait-admin-1 elasticsearch[28653]: 2020-02-11 15:58:58,768 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=IfAny, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.action.IfAny].
Feb 11 15:58:58 crait-admin-1 elasticsearch[28653]: 2020-02-11 15:58:58,768 main DEBUG createOrCondition(={IfAccumulatedFileSize(exceeds=1048576), IfLastModified(age=P3D)})
Feb 11 15:58:58 crait-admin-1 elasticsearch[28653]: 2020-02-11 15:58:58,769 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=IfFileName, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.action.IfFileName].
Feb 11 15:58:58 crait-admin-1 elasticsearch[28653]: 2020-02-11 15:58:58,770 main DEBUG createNameCondition(glob="elasticsearch-*.json.gz", regex="null", ={})
Feb 11 15:58:58 crait-admin-1 elasticsearch[28653]: 2020-02-11 15:58:58,770 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=Delete, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.action.DeleteAction].
Feb 11 15:58:58 crait-admin-1 elasticsearch[28653]: 2020-02-11 15:58:58,774 main DEBUG createDeleteAction(basePath="/var/log/elasticsearch", followLinks="false", maxDepth="1", testMode="false", PathSorter=null, ={IfAny[IfAccumulatedFileSize(exceeds=1048576), IfLastModified(age=P3D)], IfFileName(glob:elasticsearch-*.json.gz)}, ScriptCondition=null, Configuration)
Feb 11 15:58:58 crait-admin-1 elasticsearch[28653]: 2020-02-11 15:58:58,775 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=DefaultRolloverStrategy, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.DefaultRolloverStrategy].
Feb 11 15:58:58 crait-admin-1 elasticsearch[28653]: 2020-02-11 15:58:58,779 main DEBUG DefaultRolloverStrategy$Builder(max="null", min="null", fileIndex="null", compressionLevel="null", ={DeleteAction[basePath=/var/log/elasticsearch, options=[], maxDepth=1, conditions=[IfAny[IfAccumulatedFileSize(exceeds=1048576), IfLastModified(age=P3D)], IfFileName(glob:elasticsearch-*.json.gz)]]}, stopCustomActionsOnError="null", tempCompressedFilePattern="null", Configuration)
Feb 11 15:58:58 crait-admin-1 elasticsearch[28653]: 2020-02-11 15:58:58,779 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=appender, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender].
Feb 11 15:58:58 crait-admin-1 elasticsearch[28653]: 2020-02-11 15:58:58,786 main DEBUG RollingFileAppender$Builder(fileName="/var/log/elasticsearch/elasticsearch_server.json", filePattern="/var/log/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.json.gz", append="null", locking="null", Policies(CompositeTriggeringPolicy(policies=[TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy(nextRolloverMillis=0, interval=1, modulate=true)])), DefaultRolloverStrategy(DefaultRolloverStrategy(min=1, max=7, useMax=true)), advertise="null", advertiseUri="null", createOnDemand="null", filePermissions="null", fileOwner="null", fileGroup="null", bufferedIo="null", bufferSize="null", immediateFlush="null", ignoreExceptions="null", ESJsonLayout(ESJsonLayout{patternLayout={"type": "server", "timestamp": "%d{yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss,SSSZZ}", "level": "%p", "component": "%c{1.}", "cluster.name": "${sys:es.logs.cluster_name}", "node.name": "%node_name", "message": "%notEmpty{%enc{%marker}{JSON} }%enc{%.-10000m}{JSON}"%notEmpty{, %node_and_cluster_id }%exceptionAsJson }
Feb 11 15:58:58 crait-admin-1 elasticsearch[28653]: }), name="rolling", Configuration, Filter=null)
Feb 11 15:58:58 crait-admin-1 elasticsearch[28653]: 2020-02-11 15:58:58,792 main DEBUG Starting RollingFileManager /var/log/elasticsearch/elasticsearch_server.json
Feb 11 15:58:58 crait-admin-1 elasticsearch[28653]: 2020-02-11 15:58:58,796 main DEBUG PluginManager 'FileConverter' found 2 plugins
Feb 11 15:58:58 crait-admin-1 elasticsearch[28653]: 2020-02-11 15:58:58,798 main DEBUG Setting prev file time to 2020-02-10T15:16:18.326+0000
Feb 11 15:58:58 crait-admin-1 elasticsearch[28653]: 2020-02-11 15:58:58,801 main DEBUG Initializing triggering policy CompositeTriggeringPolicy(policies=[TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy(nextRolloverMillis=0, interval=1, modulate=true)])
Feb 11 15:58:58 crait-admin-1 elasticsearch[28653]: 2020-02-11 15:58:58,802 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=layout, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout].
Feb 11 15:58:58 crait-admin-1 elasticsearch[28653]: 2020-02-11 15:58:58,804 main DEBUG PatternLayout$Builder(pattern="[%d{ISO8601}][%-5p][%-25c{1.}] [%node_name]%marker %m%n", PatternSelector=null, Configuration, Replace=null, charset="null", alwaysWriteExceptions="null", disableAnsi="null", noConsoleNoAnsi="null", header="null", footer="null")
Feb 11 15:58:58 crait-admin-1 elasticsearch[28653]: 2020-02-11 15:58:58,804 main DEBUG PluginManager 'Converter' found 48 plugins
Feb 11 15:58:58 crait-admin-1 elasticsearch[28653]: 2020-02-11 15:58:58,806 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=appender, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.ConsoleAppender].
Feb 11 15:58:58 crait-admin-1 elasticsearch[28653]: 2020-02-11 15:58:58,808 main DEBUG ConsoleAppender$Builder(target="null", follow="null", direct="null", bufferedIo="null", bufferSize="null", immediateFlush="null", ignoreExceptions="null", PatternLayout([%d{ISO8601}][%-5p][%-25c{1.}] [%node_name]%marker %m%n), name="console", Configuration, Filter=null)
Feb 11 15:58:58 crait-admin-1 elasticsearch[28653]: 2020-02-11 15:58:58,811 main DEBUG Starting OutputStreamManager SYSTEM_OUT.false.false
Feb 11 15:58:58 crait-admin-1 elasticsearch[28653]: 2020-02-11 15:58:58,811 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=layout, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout].
Feb 11 15:58:58 crait-admin-1 elasticsearch[28653]: 2020-02-11 15:58:58,812 main DEBUG PatternLayout$Builder(pattern="[%d{ISO8601}][%-5p][%-25c{1.}] [%node_name]%marker %m%n", PatternSelector=null, Configuration, Replace=null, charset="null", alwaysWriteExceptions="null", disableAnsi="null", noConsoleNoAnsi="null", header="null", footer="null")
Feb 11 15:58:58 crait-admin-1 elasticsearch[28653]: 2020-02-11 15:58:58,813 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy].
Feb 11 15:58:58 crait-admin-1 elasticsearch[28653]: 2020-02-11 15:58:58,814 main DEBUG TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy$Builder(interval="1", modulate="true", maxRandomDelay="null")
Feb 11 15:58:58 crait-admin-1 elasticsearch[28653]: 2020-02-11 15:58:58,814 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=Policies, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.CompositeTriggeringPolicy].
Feb 11 15:58:58 crait-admin-1 elasticsearch[28653]: 2020-02-11 15:58:58,815 main DEBUG createPolicy(={TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy(nextRolloverMillis=0, interval=1, modulate=true)})
Feb 11 15:58:58 crait-admin-1 elasticsearch[28653]: 2020-02-11 15:58:58,815 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=IfAccumulatedFileSize, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.action.IfAccumulatedFileSize].
Feb 11 15:58:58 crait-admin-1 elasticsearch[28653]: 2020-02-11 15:58:58,817 main DEBUG createFileSizeCondition(exceeds="1MB", ={})
Feb 11 15:58:58 crait-admin-1 elasticsearch[28653]: 2020-02-11 15:58:58,817 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=IfLastModified, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.action.IfLastModified].
Feb 11 15:58:58 crait-admin-1 elasticsearch[28653]: 2020-02-11 15:58:58,818 main DEBUG createAgeCondition(age="P3D", ={})
Feb 11 15:58:58 crait-admin-1 elasticsearch[28653]: 2020-02-11 15:58:58,818 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=IfAny, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.action.IfAny].
Feb 11 15:58:58 crait-admin-1 elasticsearch[28653]: 2020-02-11 15:58:58,819 main DEBUG createOrCondition(={IfAccumulatedFileSize(exceeds=1048576), IfLastModified(age=P3D)})
Feb 11 15:58:58 crait-admin-1 elasticsearch[28653]: 2020-02-11 15:58:58,819 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=IfFileName, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.action.IfFileName].
Feb 11 15:58:58 crait-admin-1 elasticsearch[28653]: 2020-02-11 15:58:58,820 main DEBUG createNameCondition(glob="elasticsearch-*.log.gz", regex="null", ={})
Feb 11 15:58:58 crait-admin-1 elasticsearch[28653]: 2020-02-11 15:58:58,820 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=Delete, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.action.DeleteAction].
Feb 11 15:58:58 crait-admin-1 elasticsearch[28653]: 2020-02-11 15:58:58,822 main DEBUG createDeleteAction(basePath="/var/log/elasticsearch", followLinks="false", maxDepth="1", testMode="false", PathSorter=null, ={IfAny[IfAccumulatedFileSize(exceeds=1048576), IfLastModified(age=P3D)], IfFileName(glob:elasticsearch-*.log.gz)}, ScriptCondition=null, Configuration)
Feb 11 15:58:58 crait-admin-1 elasticsearch[28653]: 2020-02-11 15:58:58,822 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=DefaultRolloverStrategy, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.DefaultRolloverStrategy].
Feb 11 15:58:58 crait-admin-1 elasticsearch[28653]: 2020-02-11 15:58:58,823 main DEBUG DefaultRolloverStrategy$Builder(max="null", min="null", fileIndex="null", compressionLevel="null", ={DeleteAction[basePath=/var/log/elasticsearch, options=[], maxDepth=1, conditions=[IfAny[IfAccumulatedFileSize(exceeds=1048576), IfLastModified(age=P3D)], IfFileName(glob:elasticsearch-*.log.gz)]]}, stopCustomActionsOnError="null", tempCompressedFilePattern="null", Configuration)
Feb 11 15:58:58 crait-admin-1 elasticsearch[28653]: 2020-02-11 15:58:58,823 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=appender, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender].
Feb 11 15:58:58 crait-admin-1 elasticsearch[28653]: 2020-02-11 15:58:58,824 main DEBUG RollingFileAppender$Builder(fileName="/var/log/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.log", filePattern="/var/log/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-%d{yyyy-MM-dd-hh-mm}-%i.log.gz", append="null", locking="null", Policies(CompositeTriggeringPolicy(policies=[TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy(nextRolloverMillis=0, interval=1, modulate=true)])), DefaultRolloverStrategy(DefaultRolloverStrategy(min=1, max=7, useMax=true)), advertise="null", advertiseUri="null", createOnDemand="null", filePermissions="null", fileOwner="null", fileGroup="null", bufferedIo="null", bufferSize="null", immediateFlush="null", ignoreExceptions="null", PatternLayout([%d{ISO8601}][%-5p][%-25c{1.}] [%node_name]%marker %m%n), name="rolling_old", Configuration, Filter=null)
Feb 11 15:58:58 crait-admin-1 elasticsearch[28653]: 2020-02-11 15:58:58,825 main DEBUG Starting RollingFileManager /var/log/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.log
Feb 11 15:58:58 crait-admin-1 elasticsearch[28653]: 2020-02-11 15:58:58,826 main DEBUG PluginManager 'FileConverter' found 2 plugins
Feb 11 15:58:58 crait-admin-1 elasticsearch[28653]: 2020-02-11 15:58:58,827 main DEBUG Setting prev file time to 2020-02-10T15:16:18.326+0000
Feb 11 15:58:58 crait-admin-1 elasticsearch[28653]: 2020-02-11 15:58:58,827 main DEBUG Initializing triggering policy CompositeTriggeringPolicy(policies=[TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy(nextRolloverMillis=0, interval=1, modulate=true)])
Feb 11 15:58:58 crait-admin-1 elasticsearch[28653]: 2020-02-11 15:58:58,828 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=appenders, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppendersPlugin].
Feb 11 15:58:58 crait-admin-1 elasticsearch[28653]: 2020-02-11 15:58:58,829 main DEBUG createAppenders(={rolling, console, rolling_old})
Feb 11 15:58:58 crait-admin-1 elasticsearch[28653]: 2020-02-11 15:58:58,829 main WARN No Root logger was configured, creating default ERROR-level Root logger with Console appender
Feb 11 15:58:58 crait-admin-1 elasticsearch[28653]: 2020-02-11 15:58:58,830 main DEBUG Starting OutputStreamManager SYSTEM_OUT.false.false-4
Feb 11 15:58:58 crait-admin-1 elasticsearch[28653]: 2020-02-11 15:58:58,831 main DEBUG Configuration org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.composite.CompositeConfiguration@769a1df5 [configurations=[org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.properties.PropertiesConfiguration@41f69e84], mergeStrategy=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.composite.DefaultMergeStrategy@7975d1d8, rootNode=null, listeners=[org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext@3e78b6a5], pluginPackages=[], pluginManager=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginManager@2438dcd, isShutdownHookEnabled=true, shutdownTimeoutMillis=0, scriptManager=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.script.ScriptManager@5023bb8b] initialized
Feb 11 15:58:58 crait-admin-1 elasticsearch[28653]: 2020-02-11 15:58:58,831 main DEBUG Starting configuration org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.composite.CompositeConfiguration@769a1df5 [configurations=[org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.properties.PropertiesConfiguration@41f69e84], mergeStrategy=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.composite.DefaultMergeStrategy@7975d1d8, rootNode=null, listeners=[org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext@3e78b6a5], pluginPackages=[], pluginManager=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginManager@2438dcd, isShutdownHookEnabled=true, shutdownTimeoutMillis=0, scriptManager=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.script.ScriptManager@5023bb8b]
Feb 11 15:58:58 crait-admin-1 elasticsearch[28653]: 2020-02-11 15:58:58,832 main DEBUG Started configuration org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.composite.CompositeConfiguration@769a1df5 [configurations=[org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.properties.PropertiesConfiguration@41f69e84], mergeStrategy=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.composite.DefaultMergeStrategy@7975d1d8, rootNode=null, listeners=[org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext@3e78b6a5], pluginPackages=[], pluginManager=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginManager@2438dcd, isShutdownHookEnabled=true, shutdownTimeoutMillis=0, scriptManager=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.script.ScriptManager@5023bb8b] OK.
Feb 11 15:58:58 crait-admin-1 elasticsearch[28653]: 2020-02-11 15:58:58,832 main DEBUG Shutting down OutputStreamManager SYSTEM_OUT.false.false-1
Feb 11 15:58:58 crait-admin-1 elasticsearch[28653]: 2020-02-11 15:58:58,833 main DEBUG Shut down OutputStreamManager SYSTEM_OUT.false.false-1, all resources released: true
Feb 11 15:58:58 crait-admin-1 elasticsearch[28653]: 2020-02-11 15:58:58,833 main DEBUG Appender DefaultConsole-1 stopped with status true
Feb 11 15:58:58 crait-admin-1 elasticsearch[28653]: 2020-02-11 15:58:58,833 main DEBUG Stopped org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.builder.impl.BuiltConfiguration@3ba987b8 OK
Feb 11 15:58:58 crait-admin-1 elasticsearch[28653]: 2020-02-11 15:58:58,834 main DEBUG JMX disabled for Log4j2. Not registering MBeans.
Feb 11 15:58:58 crait-admin-1 elasticsearch[28653]: 2020-02-11 15:58:58,834 main DEBUG LoggerContext[name=c387f44, org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext@3e78b6a5] started OK with configuration org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.composite.CompositeConfiguration@769a1df5 [configurations=[org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.properties.PropertiesConfiguration@41f69e84], mergeStrategy=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.composite.DefaultMergeStrategy@7975d1d8, rootNode=null, listeners=[org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext@3e78b6a5], pluginPackages=[], pluginManager=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginManager@2438dcd, isShutdownHookEnabled=true, shutdownTimeoutMillis=0, scriptManager=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.script.ScriptManager@5023bb8b].
Feb 11 15:59:13 crait-admin-1 systemd[1]: Started Elasticsearch.
-- Subject: Unit elasticsearch.service has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit elasticsearch.service has finished starting up.
--
-- The start-up result is done.
Feb 11 15:59:13 crait-admin-1 polkitd[1364]: Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-process:28623:129219889 (system bus name :1.10334, object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_US.UTF-8) (disconnected from bus)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. A tip: it will help your question get answered if you post what results you get from this (are there errors, and if so what, and if not then what is the difference between your expected result and the actual result).

Comment: @levininja I don't get any errors, elasticsearch service starts normally. I just don't see any log deletion in effect.

Comment: It seems odd that you specified the base path as ${sys:es.logs.base_path} for the file names but then hardcoded /var/log/elasticsearch as the basepath of the delete. How are we to know they are the same. It would be helpful if you added status = DEBUG so we could see where the files were created and what happened at rollover.

Comment: @rgoers i have added the debug logs. do you mind taking a look.

Comment: Your log shows the configuration doesn't quite match the log. The debug output is showing a duration of 3 days for logs to be deleted while the configuration shows 1 day. Also, the debug logs don't show a rollover so I can't determine what is happening there. Finally, I just noticed that the DeleteAction logs at trace so you would need status=trace to see what it is doing.

Comment: @rgoers oh sorry about that. I was making some changes this morning so the logs are after the changes. Ideally i want to keep the logs for 3 days. I will post rollover logs when i see them. is there a way to trigger logrolling in elastic/log4j2 manually ?

Comment: It has to meet the rollover criteria. With TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy that is based on the pattern in the %d{} of the file pattern.

Comment: @rgoers thanks for all the help provided. with minor changes it worked. You have been a great help

Comment: @saumil would you mind sharing the small change that made it work?